# Perl: how to do math operations within a command?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to position the terminal cursor using `print` and `\e`

Syntax: `print "\e[<row>;<col>H";`

However, I want to use the value of `row` multiplied by 2.

**Can I do this in perl without an extra variable assignment?** If not, I guess multipying `row` by 2 on a different line isn't the worst thing ever...

```
$row = 1; $col = 1;
print "\e[$row;${col}H";     # Correct syntax, works fine.
print "\e[$row*2;${col}H";   # Does not work
print "\e[($row*2);${col}H"; # Does not work
```

---

Bash equivalent: `echo -ne "\e[$(($row*2));${col}H"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$row = 1; $col = 1;
print "\e[$row;${col}H";     # Correct syntax, works fine.
print "\e[".($row*2).";${col}H";   # Does not work
print "\e[".($row*2).";${col}H"; # Does not work
```

Do the calculation outside of the string and concatinate the result.

Answer (score 6):

[printf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf.html) can be used to cleanly separate your calculations from the printed format:

```
$row = 1; $col = 1;
printf "\e[%d;%dH", $row, $col;
printf "\e[%d;%dH", $row*2, $col;
```

Answer (score 5):

Perl doesn't interpolate expressions, just variables and dereferences (it evaluates expressions inside the dereference, though). To get your desired result, you'll have to evaluate the expression outside the string with the concatenation operator `.`:

```
print "\e[".($row * 2).";${col}H";
```

Alternatively, you could use `printf`:

```
printf "\e[%d;%dH", $row*2, $col;
```

As Diab Jerius has pointed out, you also could use the [Baby Cart](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perlsecret/lib/perlsecret.pod#Baby-cart) "hidden operator".

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using the [Baby Cart](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perlsecret/lib/perlsecret.pod#Baby-cart) operator

```
$row = 1; $col = 1;
print "\e[@{[ $row*2 ]};${col}H";
```